Why Ubuntu will boot when I move the lid?
I wanted to keep Ubuntu running even when I closed the lid so I edited /etc/systemd/logind.conf and set HandleLidSwitch to ignore. It worked fine but I realized that my laptop would be without battery when I opened it time to time and it was powered on, even when I shut it down using gnome menu or by terminal. Now I cannot shut the system down as a change of the lid would cause the system to power on. How do I fix this?
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with NVIDIA RTX 4050 using the GPU driver version 555.58.02.
